# Apache Flink, Kafka consumer - org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender retrying (2147483646 attempts left). Error: NETWORK_EXCEPTION

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-producer-api

We are using Apache flink kafka consumer to consume the payload . We are facing the delay in processing intermittently. We have added the logs in our business logic and everything looks good. But keep on getting the below error.

```
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-44] WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender  - [Producer clientId=producer-44] Got error produce response with correlation id 82 on topic-partition topicname-ingress-0, retrying (2147483646 attempts left). Error: NETWORK_EXCEPTION. Error Message: Disconnected from node 0
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-44] WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender  - [Producer clientId=producer-44] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition topicnamae-ingress-0 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NetworkException: Disconnected from node 0. Going to request metadata update now
```

Comment: This implies that there are network issues between the Flink cluster and the Kafka cluster. There have been a couple of issues between Kafka and Flink which were caused by a bug in the Kafka Client. Flink 1.16 will contain an update for that (which is expected in the next week or so). Are you on the latest versions for Flink and Kafka?

Comment: Thanks for the update @Martin. We are using a flink version 1.15 so far. Lets try that and keep posted here

Comment: Flink 1.16 is now available, so it will be interesting to see if you will still experience this issue

Comment: Martijn still the issue exist . We are facing the same exception and exactly 30 sec delay .

Comment: 2022-10-31 16:36:26.979 [ED-Process-Func -> (Filter -> event-state-db -> Filter -> Sink: Writer -> Sink: Committer, Filter -> Map -> event-state-db -> Filter -> Sink: Writer -> Sink: Committer, event-detection-state-fsm -> Sink: Writer -> Sink: Committer, filter-detected-event -> Map -> Flat Map -> Sink: Writer -> Sink: Committer) (1/1)#0] INFO  c.p.c.s.e.function.EventDetectionProcessFunction  - Method processElement execution ended at:Mon Oct 31 16:36:26 UTC 2022

Comment: 2022-10-31 16:36:56.925 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender  - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Got error produce response with correlation id 107 on topic-partition ccs-fsm-ingress-0, retrying (2147483646 attempts left). Error: NETWORK_EXCEPTION. Error Message: Disconnected from node 0

Comment: 2-10-31 16:36:56.925 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender  - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition ccs-fsm-ingress-0 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NetworkException: Disconnected from node 0. Going to request metadata update now
202

Comment: 2022-10-31 16:39:16.147 [Source: ED-Kafka-Src -> SignalString-Map-SignalWrapper -> Filter -> Map -> pattern-matching-fsm-state -> Sink: Writer -> Sink: Committer (1/1)#0] INFO  c.pwc.ccs.sqs.eventdetection.service.SignalProcessingService  - Method convertToSignalWrapper execution started at:Mon Oct 31 16:39:16 UTC 2022

Comment: This still implies network connectivity issues between your Flink and Kafka cluster